# Render certain characters depending on condition

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a virtual keyboard that will allow a user to type any letter via gaze tracking.

I have a set of charcters contained in this set;

```
fullSet = {0: "A", 1: "B", 2: "C", 3: "D", 4: "E",
            5:"F", 6: "G", 7:"H", 8:"I", 9:"J",
            10:"K", 11:"L", 12:"M", 13:"N", 14:"O",
            15: "P", 16: "Q", 17: "R", 18: "S", 19: "T",
            20:"U", 21: "V", 22:"W", 23:"X", 24:"Y",
            25:"Z", 26:"SPACE", 27:"DEL", 28:"ENT"}
```

I'll be displaying half on the left side of a cv2 keyboard and half on the right side and using a gaze tracker to pick what side the desired character is on.

Characters ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO will appear on the left side and I want the user to be able to move their head left for 3 seconds which will then display a split like below

ABCDEFG    HIJKLMNO

And this will continue until the user is able to select between two characters.

My question is how do I render specific characters using their index on a cv2  window?

Comment: do you mean render keyboard or selected char ? cv2 has functions to draw rectangle and to print text. And when you will draw rectangle with char then you should create dictionary `{(x1,y1,x2,y2):"A", ...}` and later you can use gaze position to check which char was selected.

Comment: maybe if you would keep char as list then you could use `middle = len(fullset)//2` ; `left = fullset[ :middle]` ; `right = fullset[ middle: ]`. And you can also repeate it for smaller parts - `middle_left = len(left)//2` ; `left_left = left[ :middle_left ]`; `left_right = left[ middle_left: ]`, etc.

Comment: you can draw rectangles, circles and characters at specific coordinates on the CV2 window object. Check out cv2.putText() in particular where you can specify several parameters such as color, size, thickness and position.